# Show hidden div on click from jqgrid TD not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using MVC5.  I have a jqgrid that when any TD is clicked on, I want to show a hidden div.  I can capture the TD click, but I can't get the div to show.  The div is hidden using bootstraps 'hidden' class, which looks like all it does is set the display to none.

jquery:

```
    $("#mobile-grid").on("click", "td", function () {
        $("#mobile-options").toggleClass('hidden show');
    })
```

jqgrid div:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="mobile-grid"></table>
```

Hidden div:

```
<div id="mobile-options" class="hidden">
  <div class="tile tile-blue">
     <h2>Required Mobile Options</h2>
   .....
   </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried:

```
    $("#mobile-grid").on("click", "td", function () {
        $("#mobile-options").toggle();
    })
```

and

```
    $("#mobile-grid").on("click", "td", function () {
        $("#mobile-options").show();
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the 'hidden' attribute for the hidden div, insead of the hidden class, and then you can toggle. Like this:

```js
$('#mobile-grid tr').on("click", notify);

function notify() {
  alert("clicked");
  $('#mobile-options').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="mobile-grid">
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td id="mobile-options" hidden>hidden td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Jqgrid builds the table structure.  I can fire an alert with the existing code, so I know the function is firing on TD click.  It just doesn't show the hidden div.

Comment: oops, I forgot that.  there you go.

Comment: I hadn't heard of that attribute.  it worked.  I wonder why the hidden class doesn't...  Anywho, thank you!  If you amend your answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: you CAN use the hidden class, but then you have to use different jQuery calls to remove/add the class to that hidden div. I think the attribute is better. Also, answer amended. :)